# setState not triggering re-render in React even though it changes the state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, state

I am currently trying to render a child component twice inside a Redux-Form and having the following issue. The first instance of the child component renders without problems after clicking a button and updating the state. However, the second instance of the component doesn't render after clicking a button and updating the state. Also, after clicking the second button,  when I click the button inside the div of the first instance of the component, it does render the second child component with the props that I passed to it. Here is my code:

```
addSources() {
  this.setState({
    sources: this.state.sources.concat(this.props.values.sourceIp)
  });
}

addDestinations() {
  const newDestIP = this.props.values.destinationIp;
  const oldDestinations = this.state.destinations2;
  const newDestinations = newDestIP.concat(oldDestinations);

  this.setState({
    destinations:[...this.state.destinations, newDestinations]
  });
}

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  return true;
}

render() {
const { handleSubmit, onChange, values} = this.props;
return(
  <div>
    <form>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div style={chipsStyles}>
            <Chips ipList={this.state.sources} />
          </div>
          <Field name="sourceIp" component={TextField} 
          hintText='198.162.10.10' floatingLabelText='Source IP'/>
          <div><RaisedButton onClick=
          {this.addProtocolChips}>Add</RaisedButton></div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div style={chipsStyles}>
            <Chips ipList={this.state.destinations} />
          </div>
          <Field name="destinationIp" component={TextField} 
          hintText='198.162.10.10' floatingLabelText='Destinatoin 
          IP'/>
          <div><RaisedButton onClick=
            {this.addDestinations}>Add</RaisedButton></div>
          </div>
       </form>
    </div>
  )
 }
```

Comment: You might need to change `addDestinations` to an arrow function, and use  `this.setState(prevState => ({ destinations:[...this.prevState.destinations, newDestinations] }));` instead of `this.state`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work either.